# Unable to get the right exit code from a script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sftp, exit

I have a script which connects to a remote server via SFTP and get some file from there. My script goes like this:

```
/usr/bin/sftp USER@remote.server.com <<EOF
lcd /dir1/dir2/dir3
cd /rsdir1/rsdir2/rsdir3
get file_pattern`date -d "last month" +%m%Y`.csv
EOF
rc=$?
        if [[ $rc != 0 ]]
           then
        echo "Error occured getting file and the script abended with error code $rc" `date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S"`
            exit 1
    else
    echo "Successfully transferred the file" `date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S"`
        fi
```

However, even if the script doesn't find the file with the pattern it goes to the **else** part of the script and gives me the output on the screen as

```
Connecting to remote.server.com...
sftp> lcd /dir1/dir2/dir3
sftp> cd /rsdir1/rsdir2/rsdir3
sftp> get file_pattern032014.csv
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
File "/rsdir1/rsdir2/rsdir3/file_pattern032014.csv" not found.
Successfully transferred the file YYYY-MM-DD-24HH.MI.SS
```

Any advices on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `lftp` too instead of trying to script with `sftp`. It's not really meant to be used in that fashion. I show an example doing something like this using `lftp` here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/ftp-bulk-download-and-rename/88717#88717

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got the right return code, sftp session executed correctly so the return code is 0.
You should use `scp` instead, it does not returns 0 if it fails to copy.

You could do something like :

```
file=file_pattern`date -d "last month" +%m%Y`.csv 
remote=USER@remote.server.com:/rsdir1/rsdir2/rsdir3/$file
local=/rsdir1/rsdir2/rsdir3/$file

if scp -q $remote $local
then
    echo "Successfully transferred the file" `date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S"`
else
    echo "Error occured getting file and the script abended with error code $?" `date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S"`
    exit 1
fi
```

EDIT: I changed the copy target to a file name : If you copy to a directory and that directory is missing, you will create a file that has the directory name.

Comment: Quick question, I am having the same trouble with pulling the file (here, I have a file name pattern instead of exact file name) using FTP script. Any recommendations from your side on this? Or should this be posted as a different question? Not sure. please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`/usr/bin/sftp -b - USER@remote.server.com <<EOF
...`

The "-b -" puts sftp in batch mode while still reading from the command line.  Batch mode will (on my system) exit sftp and return a non-zero exit code when one of the sftp commands fails.

Comment: since you mention your system, what version of sftp do you have installed?