# Unable to move files with SFTP

Tags: shell-script, sftp

I'm trying to move files from one location to another on the remote server using sftp below:

```
for i in a b c d
do
sftp $REMUSR <<EOM>>$OUT 2>&1
rename $SOURDIR/sample_${i}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz $REMDIR
quit
EOM
:
:
done
```

But I get the message:

> Couldn't rename file "/source/sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz" to       "/destin/": No such file or directory

Though this file exists under the `/source` directory which I've verified:

```
$ ls -l sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz
-rw-r--r--  1 prd admin 112 May 23 09:16 sample_a_20140330.gz
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88710/ftp-bulk-download-and-rename/88717#88717. The regex within the `sftp` doesn't work the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

FTP's rename command doesn't compute regular expressions. It interprets the regex as filename that it not present on the system. You are using `sftp`. Another approach is to use `ssh`:

```
for i in a b c d
do
  ssh $user@$host "mv $SOURDIR/sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz $REMDIR"
done
```

Comment: but @chaos, in one of my earlier snippets:for i in a b c d
do
   sftp $REMUSR <<EOM>>$OUT 2>&1
   put $LOCAL_DIR/sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz $REMOTE_DIR
  quit
EOM worked and it placed the sample_a_20140330.gz file on the remote server. Does this mean put computes reg exp but rename does not? Am slightly confused here

Comment: Yes, `rename` just accepts explicit filenames. A regex or a wildcard could match multiple files. `put` accepts globs. See the manpage of `sftp`: `put: local-path may contain glob(3) characters and may match multiple files.`

Comment: If I'm sure of having the files in the required format in the $SOURDIR on the server, is there a way to just move all of them to $REMDIR by giving something like rename $SOURDIR/* $REMDIR? Again, am not sure if rename recognises * here, because it didn't work when I tried:-(

Comment: No, rename does not recognise regexes or globs or wildcarts (*, ?), just simple filenames.

Comment: Am trying something like this: for i in a b c d do fname=`ls sample_${i}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz` sftp $REMUSR <<EOM>>$OUT 2>&1
rename $SOURDIR/$fname $REMDIR
quit
EOM
:
:
done ......but no luck